# Can't find OpenJDK 8 in Application

Tags: java, openjdk

I installed OpenJDK 8 and I am trying to run an application but I can't find it when I choose "Open with other application" then "All applications".

I know for sure that I have installed it since if I type `java -version` this appears:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Which application are you trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And then go to "Show Applications" [image] and check if appears